# Расширения chrome (вкладки)

Tags: chrome-extension

Мне нужно, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу выполнялось действие. Для этого нужен chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab){}). Какие разрешения для этого нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум нужно указать "permissions": ["tabs"]
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/declare-permissions
Обратите внимание, что доступ к tabs будет только у background.js (service_worker), из файла content.js доступа к tabs не будет.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).